# Is there a function to calculate weekdays from today PHP

Tags: php, days

I'm writing a code which need to calculate the number of weekdays from a date to today. 
I just have today's date and with that i want to pass a number to the function so it can return me back the number of weekdays since x days.

e.g  :

```
function getWorkingDays($number){
    // code...
    return $value;
}

// if we are monday
getWorkingDays(2) // return Thursday's date
```

I got this problem since two days now and i'm getting very boring, hope someone got a solution.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use the Carbon (https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) library? That would make the task fairly easy.

Comment: Take a look at DateInterval https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php

Comment: please mark the answer that is best for you

Comment: oh sorry it's my first question there, done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to do with the DateTime object:

```
$date = date_create('2020-01-06'); //a Monday 
$numberWeekdays = 2;
$date->modify('-'.$numberWeekdays.' weekdays');

echo $date->format('l Y-m-d');
//Thursday 2020-01-02
```

If you need Today as the basis , you can also use date_create('Today').